# How to get a list of all available Com Ports in C# with asp.net 4

Tags: c#, serial-port

How can I list all of the available com ports to my computer?

I have seen a few examples wiht .net 1.1 so I was wandering is there is not a more modern way to go about doing this?

I have my serialPort called `serialPort`

I got this code from msdn site:

```
// Get a list of serial port names. 
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");

// Display each port name to the console. 
foreach(string port in ports)
{
    Console.WriteLine(port);
}
```

It give me the following error:
    The name "SerialPort" Does not exist in the current context

I have tried changing it to a small s, and I then get this error:

```
Member 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()' cannot be accessed with an instance        reference; qualify it with a type name instead
```

Comment: Well, "string[] ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();" works fine and finds out my "COM1" port

Comment: Do review the wisdom of connecting serial devices to your web server.  That tends to require a very long cable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`The name "SerialPort" Does not exist in the current context` error means you don't have the required references and/or namespace imports set on your project/file.

`'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()' cannot be accessed with an instance        reference; qualify it with a type name instead` means you are trying to call a static method on an object instance (which is, obviously, impossible).

You need to fully qualify namespaces in your method call:

```
string[] ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

or add a `using` directive:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
.....
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```